# Can't access notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a ListView that I update from my SQLite database and I have set an onItemLongClickListener to help me delete from my database through a dialog interface. However, I can't seem to have access to notifyDataSetChanges not even if I make my adapter global.

This is my list population function

```
private void populateListView() {
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
       last_date = expire_Date(data.getString(4));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(last_date);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
        Date currDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dates = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        currDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int differenceDates;
        differenceDates = difOfDay(c, currDate);
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = month+1;
        String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        String first_row =data.getString(3) + " (" + data.getString(1) + ")\n";
        String second_row = getResources().getString(R.string.red_info);

        listdata.add(first_row + " " + second_row + differenceDates + " (" + date + ")");
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listdata);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is my delete function:

```
public AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener myClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int position, final long id) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                .setTitle("Delete ")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        mDatabaseHelper.deletechute(position);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Parachute deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ////Here my code can't resolve my adapter///
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();
        return false;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This just looks firstly like a plain Java Variable scope problem but there are other problems as well but it is very hard to tell without more code.
So.

## Problem 1

The `adapter` is defined and initialized in the scope of `populateListView`.
When this method ends, the reference is removed and the variables memory area can be deleted by garbage collection.

I suggest you read https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

You could fix this by defining the `adapter` as a private variable in the scope of your Activity Class and then it will be available to all methods in the class.

## Problem 2

If you have fixed `Problem 1` then `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` still won't do anything.
This is because you are notifying it that the `ArrayList<String> listdata` has changed when you have done nothing to update the List and you cannot update it because again there is not available reference to `listdata` because it was also defined in local scope.

This again could be fixed by making `listdata` a private variable in the scope of your Activity but that leads to:-

## Problem 3

This is a very convoluted way of doing this having to keep the database and list in sync manually.

You would be better off with a Cursor Adapter e.g. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

A guide on Cursor Adapters with Listviews at https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Then in the `OnClick` method you would update your database, and get a new Cursor of all the results again and swap the new Cursor for the old and then `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`